# How to test time from a object created to destroyed in Java?

Tags: java, performance-testing

In book effective Java(2nd), about the use of finalize method, the author tests time from a object created to destroyed in his computer. The time is 5.6 ns, after adding a finalize method, the time is 2400 ns. I want to know how to test this time.
My test code is under below,i want to use {} scope to simulate an object created and destroyed,but the compiler optimize the code, it removes the {},so i can't simulate the process, and can't test time.

```
public class Entry7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //fail test
        long start;
        long end;
        {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            Test test = new Test(1);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("end-start=" + (end - start) + " ns");

        {
            start = System.nanoTime();
            Test2 test2 = new Test2(1);
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("end-start=" + (end - start) + " ns");

    }
}

//first test,a simple object, without finalize method
class Test {
    private int a;

    public Test(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }


}

//second test with finalize method.
class Test2 {
    private int a;

    public Test2(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
        //if invoke this method,print some information
        System.out.println("finalize");
    }
}
```

The result is `end-start=624443 ns` and `end-start=463554 ns`;
This is not in line with my expectations, and my computer's performance is better than author's computer what he mentioned, but the result is so bad.

Comment: Please share what you have tried to do so far.

Comment: please add the code and clarification items to the question vs the comments.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko, perhaps I treat Java as C ,I don't know the compile of Java.I think leave that {} scope,the object will be destroyed.

Comment: I'm not sure what Josh Bloch means by "the time to create and destroy a simple object". Unlike C++, Java doesn't have a concept of destroying an object. When an object reference goes out of scope, the object simply becomes eligible for garbage collection. The garbage collection may happen minutes or hours afterwards or possibly never. Your timings are meaningless as you don't know what may have happened between start and end. Perhaps your process got swapped out by the operating system to let another process run. Perhaps the garbage collector kicked in at that point and delayed your process.

Comment: Also note, that while some sort of side effect is required for a test like this using a println would be massively skewing the result even if it worked. Whatever overhead is caused by overriding finalize method would most likely be overshadowed by overhead of pushing characters to the console.